# elasticsearch mapping exception when using dynamic templates

Tags: elasticsearch

hi i am using elasticsearch to index some documents. but the documents will have some fileds like `goal1Completion`, `goal2Completion`....goal100Completion. so i was trying to do mapping with `dynamic Templates`. so i came up with following but it throws an error:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "date": {
      "properties": {
        "sessions": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "viewId": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "webPropertyId": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "goalCompletions": {
              "match_pattern": "regex",
              "match": "goal\\d+\\w+",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}



error:"reason": "Expected map for property [fields] on field [dynamic_templates] but got a class java.lang.String"
```

what could be thee problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pull `dynamic_template` from `properties` map.

```
{
 "mappings": {
  "date": {
     "properties": {
        "sessions": {
           "type": "long"
        },
        "viewId": {
           "type": "string",
           "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "webPropertyId": {
           "type": "string",
           "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
     },
     "dynamic_templates": [                 <--- Pull this out of properties
        {
           "goalCompletions": {
              "match_pattern": "regex",
              "match": "goal\\d+\\w+",
              "mapping": {
                 "type": "long"
              }
           }
          }
       ]
     }
  }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks .just figured it out

Comment: but this solution dosent works error is gone but the mapping of `goalXXcompletion` is still `string` it should be long type as defined in mapping above

Comment: I tried to run Following query. `POST index/date
{"goal2completion":"abcde"}` . Assigning string to `goalXXcompletion`. I got the error : `{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [goal2completion]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse [goal2completion]","caused_by":{"type":"number_format_exception","reason":"For input string: \"10skfhkds\""}},"status":400}
{"goal2completion":"abcde"}`  That implies   dynamic template is working.

Comment: its wierd even i get the same error when indexing that means mapping is correct but while qurying i get this error: `RequestError: TransportError(400, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'Expected numeric type on field [ga:goal2Completions], but got [string]')`

Comment: What query are you running?

Comment: wait i think i found th mistake in my query .let me try if it works